# JavaScript operations based on formula

Tags: javascript, jquery

The above function formula I am getting from db that is dynamic. When I try to alert the result it displaces formula. The operation not performing. How should I proceed for that?

Example for formula: `quantity*rate`,`percentage*rate/100`...

```
   <script>
    function oprations(formula){
     var quantity=$('.quantity').val();
     var rate=$('.rate').val();
     var percentage=$('.percentage').val();
     var gst=$('.gst').val();
     var result=parseInt(formula);
     $('.result').text(result);
     alert(result);
     }
     </script>
```

I expect the output of operated value but it showing formula.

Comment: The only way to make that work is through the use of `eval`, which has some serious security risks one needs to be aware of. See [MDN's article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Do_not_ever_use_eval!)

Comment: take a look to [math.parse(expr)](https://mathjs.org/docs/reference/functions/parse.html)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately , using `eval()` might be your only solution, but is not safe.

`eval()` allows executing formulas but might open your code to some serious security risks.

I would suggest you to determine the format of string you are going to get as a formula, and make a function to calculate.

An example for a simple `+` formula is below:

```
function operate(text) {
    var values = text.split("+");

    return parseInt(values[0]) + parseInt(values[1]);
}

alert(operate("9+2"));
```

Comment: Thanks for replay,here + operator not a fixed may be * or % or / or more oprators in one formula.

Comment: Above is just an example. You can build your function based on your formula's pattern